# Knockout and jQuery Validation Remote: not getting latest value

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, jquery-validate

I have a knockout viewModel and am wiring up jQuery Validation for it.  One of the values, `code`, I want a remote check to ensure it's not already in use.  The problem is that in my method for the remote validation, the `self.code()` call is returning the old value instead of the new one.

My Validate code (note I also tried a "more direct" method of getting the value, to no avail - same result):

```
form.validate({
    rules: {
        'plandetail-code': {
            required: true,
            remote: {
                url: '/Plans/ValidatePlanCode',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    id: self.id(),
                    code: self.code() //form.find('[name="plandetail-code"]').val()
                }
            }
        },
        'plandetail-name': "required"                    
    }
});
```

Relevant Html:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="plandetail-code">Code</label>
    <input type="text" name="plandetail-code" data-bind="textInput: code" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

My controller action is simple, but note that `code` always comes through as the original value:

```
[HttpPost]
public string ValidatePlanCode(int? id, string code) {
    return _service.ValidatePlanCode(id, code) ? "true" : "false";
}
```

And here's my viewmodel: I run the `form.Validate({})` before applying bindings (tried putting that after as well), and in the `saveChanges` method I check `form.valid()`:

```
function PlanDetailVM(model) {

    var self = this;

    self.originalModel = model;
    self.form = $('#pgPlan-plan-detail-form');

    self.id = ko.observable(model.ID);
    self.active = ko.observable(model.Active);
    self.code = ko.observable(model.Code);
    self.name = ko.observable(model.Name);
    self.notes = ko.observable(model.notes);

    self.dirty = ko.computed(function () { return isDirty(); });

    self.save = function () { saveChanges(); }
    self.cancel = function () { cancelChanges(); }

    ko.applyBindings(self, document.getElementById('pgPlan-detail-container'));
    initValidation(self.form);

    return self;


    function initValidation(form) {

        form.validate({
            rules: {
                'plandetail-code': {
                    required: true,
                    remote: {
                        url: '/Plans/ValidatePlanCode',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {
                            id: self.id(),
                            code: self.code() //form.find('[name="plandetail-code"]').text()
                        }
                    }
                },
                'plandetail-name': "required"                    
            }
        });

    }

    function isDirty() { ... }

    function saveChanges() {

        if (!self.form.valid()) {
            return;
        }

        // ajax snipped
    }

    function cancelChanges() { ... }

}
```

Repro:

- Load initial view, Code has value AAAA
- Change Code to BBBB
- Observe controller action called
- Controller action code param = AAAA

I'm unsure why I can't get the latest value from the text input.  Am I missing something?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rules` is an `object` which is evaluated immediately, so the `data` object will get created with default values if you use `self.id()` (since it returns value not function)

so you need to use it as functions

```
form.validate({
  rules: {
    'plandetail-code': {
      required: true,
      remote: {
        url: '/Plans/ValidatePlanCode',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
          id: self.id, // function evaluated at runtime
          code: self.code
        }
      }
    },
    'plandetail-name': "required"
  }
});
```